# Why Theme.of(context).platform shows OS name instead of web?

Tags: flutter, responsive-design

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRulq.png)

As you can see I am running it on chrome, instead of showing web it prints macos. My purpose is to cutdown 10px of URL bar of chrome when using web.

I am not able to find any info for particullarly detecting web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a different way. Keeping this question as it might help others.
Though I am still wondering why Theme.of(context).platform is not showing web.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

if(KIsWeb){
//IS WEB
}
```

Comment: `Information about the environment in which the current program is running.

Platform provides information such as the operating system, the hostname of the computer, the value of environment variables, the path to the running program, and other global properties of the program being run.`

That's why `Theme.of(context).platform` is not showing web. Web is not technically a platform but a tool on that platform. More on that here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform-class.html